# Is the weak limit of unitary operators in $\ell^2$ bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, weak-convergence

Let $\mathcal{H} := \ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ and denote $e_k := (\delta_{kj})_j \in \mathcal{H}$. Now consider a sequence $(U_n)$ of unitary operators on $\mathcal{H}$ such that for each $j,k\in\mathbb{Z}$ there exists $u_{jk}\in\mathbb{C}$ with $$\left< e_j\mid U_n e_k\right> \longrightarrow u_{jk} \, (n\to \infty).$$
Then does $$\left< e_j\mid U e_k\right> := u_{jk}$$ for $j,k\in\mathbb{Z}$ define a bounded (maybe even unitary) operator $U$? I feel like it comes down to the question whether a sequence of unitary operators can converge weakly to an unbounded operator.

I would appreciate any answer or hint.

Comment: $U$ will definitely not be unitary in general, as you can see by letting $U_n e_k = e_{n+k}$, for which you should have $u_{j,k}=0$ for all $j,k$. I would guess that U also does not need to be bounded in general. The point is that you don't really have weak convergence (this would ensure boundedness of the limit), but only weak convergence on a dense set, namely on finite linear combinations of the $e_k$.